# v-html's styles are overwriting the whole app's style on vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

In `v-html` we include `HTML` contents like this `<div v-html="htmlContent">` here `htmlContent` includes many styles as well as bulk style files. In such a case, the styles that `v-html`has, gets applied for the whole app. 
I also see that from VUE documentation

> Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be
>   compiled as Vue templates.

they are not compiled with VUE templates. How can we fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if possible provide example of when the whole app's styles are overwriting

Comment: Why would you be injecting `<style>` elements inside `v-html`? They should never be in the payload to begin with.

Comment: @Terry, Let's say I have email template to be displayed on the page, in such cases the email template would include more HTML contents and styles for that contents, so there might be a lot of styles for that particular email template right?

Comment: @Subash If that’s the case, you might be better encapsulating that in an iframe actually, to avoid the email’s stylesheet from polluting your app’s stylesheet.